# Rails way to return create has many association on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have the following controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class VisitorsController < ApplicationController
  PERMITED_VISITOR_PARAMS = [
    :ipv4,
  ].freeze

  def create
    @visitor = Visitor.new(visitor_params)

    if @visitor.save
      render json: @visitor, status: :created
    else
      render json: @visitor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

And the Visitor model looks like:

```
class Visitor < ApplicationRecord
  audited

  has_many :sessions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Right now when a visitor is created, the controller returns an object:

```
{
    "id": 980190966,
    "ipv4": "177.45.75.245"
}
```

And I would like to, as part of creating a visitor, create a session and return the session_id in the response. I would like to know how to do that respecting Rails conventions.

Comment: What exactly do you want the response to be? "return the session_id in the response" is extremely vague. Please provide an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The typical response ideally would look like

```
{
    "id": 980190966,
    "ipv4": "177.45.75.245",
    "sessions": [{id: 1, name: "something", ..etc}, {}, ...etc]
}
```

To render this, use code similar to this

```
if @visitor.save
  render json: @visitor, include: [:sessions, :id, :ipv4], status: :created
else
```